# How to run a packaged java file in terminal?

Tags: java, terminal, runtime-error, package

Sorry if this might be bad question, but I made two classes belonging to the same package. I was able to compile both classes with both `javac -d . [ClassName].java` and `javac -d .. [ClassName].java` but when I try to run it, it won't work saying `Error: could not find or load main class [ClassName]`.

Here are both classes if it helps:

## 1:

```
package elevenslab;

public class Card{
  private String suit;
  private String rank;
  private int pointValue;

  public Card(String cardSuit, String cardRank, int cardPointValue){
    suit=cardSuit;
    rank=cardRank;
    pointValue=cardPointValue;
  }

  public String getSuit(){
    return suit;
  }

  public String getRank(){
    return rank;
  }

  public int getPtVal(){
    return pointValue;
  }

  public boolean matches(Card otherCard){
    if(this.getSuit().equals(otherCard.getSuit())&&this.getRank().equals(otherCard.getRank())&&this.getPtVal()==otherCard.getPtVal()){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  public String toString(){
    return rank+" of "+suit+" (point value: "+pointValue+")";
  }
}
```

## 2:

```
package elevenslab;

public class CardTester{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Card a=new Card("Hearts", "Queen", 12);
    Card b=new Card("Spades", "Ten", 10);
    Card c=new Card("Diamonds", "Ace", 1);
    System.out.println(a.toString()+"\n"+b.toString()+"\n"+c.toString());
  }
}
```

Both classes are in the same folder and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the parent folder of directory `elevenslab`. In `elevenslab` there should be two class files: `CardTester.class` and `Card.class`.

Then you should run the following command:

```
java -cp . elevenslab.CardTester
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have to include the package name on your classes.  You also must set a class path if it's not set in an environment variable or something similar.

`java -cp .;.. elevenslab.CardTester`

However if you don't have a directory named "elevenslab" I'm not sure how the class search algorithm is going to treat this, so it's possible I've given you an incomplete answer.